# Acronyms capitalisation

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, capitalization

I'm sure I am being an idiot but here goes.

I have used the `\usepackage{glossaries}` package for an acronym list. However, when I first use the

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\begin{document}

\newacronym{STOP}{STOP}{silly trial of peanuts}


blah de balh de balh \gls{STOP} end of documentnow and here are my conclusions 

\end{document}
```

the pdf compiler prints

> blah de balh de balh Silly trial of peanuts (STOP) end of document now and here are my conclusions.

I have tried `\Gls`
`\gls`
`\acrfull`
`\acrshort`
`\acrlong`

but to no avail. Its not a huge deal but if anyone knows how to change it I would be very grateful

Comment: Ahh sorry my fault yes- I have used that. I shall edit the original question

Comment: It is not *quite* clear to me what you are asking. Do you get "Silly trial of peanuts (STOP)" in your document from `\gls` and would like to see the uncapitalised "silly trial of peanuts (STOP)" instead - or something else entirely? I suggest two things: (1) Make sure the posted code compiles (it is missing a `\documentclass` and as mentioned above the brackets in `\newacronym` appear to be wrong) and shows the output you describe. (2) Explicitly mention the output you want to see and explain how it differs from what you get now.

Comment: Currently I use \gls and get "Silly trial of peanuts (STOP)", whereas I would like to see the uncapitalised "silly trial of peanuts (STOP)" instead

Comment: This is definitely not what I'm getting. The `\gls{STOP}` in https://gist.github.com/moewew/740a5a12faffbedbbb34ed857509598d produces the uncapitalised "silly trial of peanuts (STOP)" for me. Please turn your code into a fully compilable document *and* make sure that it really reproduces the undesirable behaviour (capitalised output) for you. Please also test the example document from my link. What does it produce for you? If you still get the wrong output, please post the complete `.log` file of your example document.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The document class has been updated in the question as that is the one my document uses. No errors arise just it like capitalising that first word

Comment: I ran the exact code you posted and got the uncapitalised "... balh silly trial of peanuts (STOP) end ...". Please add the `.log` of the LaTeX run on that document to your question.

Comment: I've got to go, but just so you have a data point, my version of `glossaries` reports to be `glossaries.sty    2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)`. Other possibly relevant package versions are `mfirstuc.sty    2017/11/14 v2.06 (NLCT)`, `textcase.sty    2019/09/14 v1.00`. You can get a nicely formatted list of your package versions in the `.log` by adding `\listfiles` to the very top of your document. Maybe one of those packages is outdated on your system (and has a bug or incompatibility that is resolved in my newer package version).

Comment: Thank you. I am having a look now to see if I can update it